# Cache content loaded via AJAX in Fancybox

Tags: ajax, caching, fancybox

Due to performance optimization I want to prevent users from reload fancyboxes they already loaded once. This is my code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox-effects").fancybox({
                type       : 'ajax',
                wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom'
            });
        });
```

Adding this:

```
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

to the document.ready function doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-effects").fancybox({
        type       : 'ajax',
        ajax       : { cache: true },
        wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom'
    });
});
```