# Fancybox avoid caching of ajax requests

Tags: ajax, caching, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm currently facing an annoying (suspected) cache issue with fancybox 3.4.1:

```
<a data-fancybox="" data-type="ajax" data-src="src/views/forms/SpeiseplanCreateForm.php?ValidFrom=1560117600" href="javascript:;" id="fancybox-SpeiseplanCreateForm"><button id="fancybox-SpeiseplanCreateForm-button">Speiseplan bearbeiten</button></a>
```

has a GET parameter which is then evaluated by my PHP script, however, when I click on it for the first time, it works fine, but when I change the value of `ValidFrom` via JavaScript and try to open the box a second time, the get parameter is still the same as in the first call. I assume it's related to fancybox caching the requests.

I have verified that the URL parameter is getting changed properly and I also tried disabling the cache by adding this to my header:

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".data-fancybox").fancybox({
         type       : 'ajax',
         ajax       : { cache: false }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621281/4934937

Is there a way to disable the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very dirty workaround for this. After editing the element in Firefox (Edit HTML), it worked. So I guessed it must have something in common with some weird caching (browser or fancybox, who knows).

The workaround is to create a new `a` element, remove the old `a` and append it to the old a's parent again.

```
let newElement = document.createElement("a");
newElement.setAttribute("id","fancybox-"+id)
newElement.setAttribute("data-fancybox","");
newElement.setAttribute("data-type","ajax");
newElement.setAttribute("href","javascript:;");
newElement.setAttribute("data-src",fancyboxSrc);
newElement.appendChild(button);

fancybox.outerHTML = "";
parent.appendChild(newElement);
```